# Cannot edit config after creating Azure app service yaml file

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-configuration, azure-container-apps

In Azure I created a container (Web  App for containers) and under the docker tab added yaml file for the docker config. However after creating the container I cannot find anywhere to edit this yaml file. Is the only option to delete the container and create another one ?

This seems simple but I cannot find anything despite searching online and on Azure

[image: web app container]

Answer (score 1):

To edit the YAML, select **Deployment Center** and the **Settings** tab. The YAML will be displayed in the **Config** textbox.
[image]